# C# Load a static method on class load

Tags: c#

I have a set of static variables

```
static string A;
static string B;
static string C;
...
```

that I would like to initialize.

Now, I could do

```
static string A;
...
static string Z = InitializeAllVariables();

static void InitializeAllVariables()
{
     /// Initialize all my static variables
}
```

but that's not very elegant.

Is there a way to force InitializeAllVariables() to run on class load so that I don't need to explicitly call it through a static variable definition?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at static constructors.

Comment: There is a static constructor.  `class foo { static foo(){} }`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you everyone, this has been most helpful. I even shared this with my colleagues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a static constructor.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    static string A;
    static string B;
    static string C;

    static MyClass()
    {
        A = "Hello";
        B = "World";
        C = "!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the static constructor:

```
static MyClass() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
Static SomeClass()
{
   InitializeAllVariables();
}
```